# What standards exist regarding diagnostic systems in automotive engineering?

Tags: automotive-engineering, simulation, software, standards, car

I'm designing a diagnostic system that simulates an environment and user input for a dummy vehicle. All possible critical situations are simulated in order to find out whether any errors are triggered, or if the software contains any faults or bugs.

It's a vehicle for state defense, it doesn't have OBD like normal cars, but a display with buttons with which you can seek and troubleshoot errors. I have to design a procedure for testing each new software release. I was wondering if any standard exists for testing/validating software. Just like driving cycles(NEDC, WLTP) exist for emission tests.

Do any standards(SAE, DIN, etc.) exist for this kind of thing?

Comment: Are there standards related to OBD, OBDII and Canbus etc

Comment: You should add those relevant details to your original question.

Comment: @SolarMike Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your project is defense software related I suggest taking a look at [MIL-STD-498](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIL-STD-498). The one that is close related to your question is [SOFTWARE TEST PLAN (STP)](https://web.archive.org/web/20110616201638/http://www.fisica.uniud.it/~cabras/swe/MIL-STD/498/STP-DID.PDF)

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't think standards exist that better apply.

Comment: I'm still looking into that! After the weekend i'll be working on it again. I'm sure it'll be helpful.